# documentar swagger en php con anotaciones diferidas al controlador

Tags: php, swagger, documentacion

hola chicos estoy intentando llevar un orden en un api y decidi usar swagger, ahora en PHP veo que solo se puede documentar sobre el controlador de la siguiente forma:

/**

- @SWG\Model(
- id="vps",
- required="['type', 'hostname']",
- @SWG\Property(name="hostname", type="string"),
- @SWG\Property(name="label", type="string"),
- @SWG\Property(name="type", type="string", enum="['vps', 'dedicated']")
- )

y esto considero vuelve al script larguisimo, ¿hay alguna forma de meter esas anotaciones en un yaml o json externo como lo hace node?

gracias!